# Getting the Paths from allPairsShortestPaths (or a similar function) from a NEO4J Database and not just the distances

Tags: java, neo4j, spring-data, spring-data-neo4j

So I am working on a Spring Project and I used NEO4J as a DB since the Entities have a tree-like structure. Now I need to find the nodes with the highest distance to each other.

I used the GDS plugin to get the distances of all nodes to each other, sorted them by distance and got the top few:

```
CALL gds.alpha.allShortestPaths.stream('AS-Graph', {})
YIELD sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
WITH sourceNodeId, targetNodeId, distance
WHERE gds.util.isFinite(distance) = true

MATCH (source) WHERE id(source) = sourceNodeId
MATCH (target) WHERE id(target) = targetNodeId
WITH source, target, distance WHERE source <> target

RETURN source.name AS source, target.name AS target, distance
ORDER BY distance DESC, source ASC, target ASC
LIMIT 300
```

I tried to find a way to get the paths for each source and target, but didn't find any. I only found a very old [neo4j community 1.5.3 JavaDoc](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.neo4j/neo4j/1.5.3/org/neo4j/graphalgo/impl/shortestpath/FloydWarshall.html) with a FloydWarshall class with a getCost and getPath function. But I didn't find it in the new releases and I don't think it will work with the 5.9 I'm running.

The only way I see, is getting the nodes with Spring, and then calling shortestPath over and over again. But that seems rather inefficient and I wanted to ask if someone knows a better way.

The final goal is saving the 300 longest paths into some Excel-Sheet, where each row is a path. So if there is a simpler solution, I'm all for it.